# How to match multiple words via terms in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, pattern-matching, match

My query for matching multiple words is as following,

```
{"query":
{"bool":{"must":[{"terms":{"my_field":"word1 word2"}}]}
```

upon execution, the result set is empty though data exists for the following query.
Instead of above query, if I use

`{"bool":{"must":[{"terms":{"my_field":"word1"}}]}`

then elastic-search is returning data.
How to match the complete sentence?

Comment: Text fields are `analyzed` by default, you may want to use match phrase query or change the type to `keyword` to match the entire text. Refer: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Comment: try it      {"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"wildcard":{"my_field":"\*word1\*"}},{"wildcard":{"my_field":"\*word2\*"}}]}}}

Answer (score 6):

Based on your comment on the above answer, I believe you should simply use two **term** queries inside your must query array.

```
{
  "query": 
    { "bool" :
          {
             "must":[
                        {"term":{"my_field": "word1" } },
                        {"term":{"my_field": "word2" } }
                    ] 
          } 
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to put the words in an array and see if it works. 
Like this: 
{"query": {"bool":{"must":[{"terms":{"my_field":["word1", "word2"]}}]}

here is the documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html

Hope it works =)

Comment: I want to match  word1 and word2 together .I mean i want to match the  complete sentence which includes word1 and word2 both.